# Removing Quotation Marks from Variable Names

Tags: csv, file-io, sas

I need to fix the output, and remove quotation marks around each attribute name:

> "#var1"|"var2"|"var3"|"var5" 
>   000|aaa|bbb|ccc 
>   111|ddd|eee|fff

I am importing an existing .csv file, modifying it slightly, and saving as another .csv to a different location:

```
%let infile=/.../file.csv;
%let outfile=/.../new_file.csv;

data file_file (drop=var4);
    infile "&infile" dsd dlm=',' truncover firstobs=2;
    length var1 $10 var2 $37 var3 $100 var4 $1 var5 $13 ;
    input var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $ var5 $;
    label var1 ='#var1';
run;

proc export data = file_file 
        outfile = "&outfile" 
        label dbms=csv replace;
        delimiter='|';
run;
```

The output should look like:

**#var1|var2|var3|var5** 

000|aaa|bbb|ccc 
111|ddd|eee|fff

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with a simple SAS data step.  You just need to know how many columns your delimited file has. Quotes around strings should be automatically removed when the values are read.  To remove the fourth column just don't write it back out.

```
%let infile=/.../file.csv;
%let outfile=/.../new_file.csv;

data _null_ ;
  infile "&infile" dsd dlm='|' lrecl=200000 truncover ; 
  file "&outfile" dsd dlm='|' lrecl=200000 ;
  length var1-var5 $32767 ;
  input var1-var5 ;
  put (var1-var3 var5) (+0) ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I also need to add a different label to one of the variables (var1 in this case), and conditionally modify contents of another variable:

1) label var1='#var1';
2) if var5 = 'donkey' then var3 = 'donkey '||var3;

Comment: At that point it is probably worth your time and effort to actually read the file in, make any modifications you want and then write it back out (if in fact you still need to write it back out).  Note that a varaible's label is different than its name and would have nothing to do with a CSV file since there there is no place to put a label in a CSV file.  I would suggest raising a new question with details of the transformations you need to make.